# Connecting to a server with multiple sets of credentials

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I'm developing a C# application that needs to connect to a file share (using a service-level account) to download images.

The problem I'm encountering is that the users already have a set of credentials on that share's server that they use for *other* shares.  It's like if you have a share mapped to a drive, you can't log into another share on the same server with different credentials.  So when I try and log on with separate credentials for this app's share, I get:

"error 1219: Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again."

The code I'm using to try and connect to the share from [this example](http://lookfwd.doitforme.gr/blog/media/PinvokeWindowsNetworking.cs), it uses the WNetUseConnection function.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

edit: I've found a workaround for this, I just connect with the host IP address instead of the host name.

Comment: Mind sharing how you solved it, if you did?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are disconnecting the user once they are done, otherwise it is crowding the server and it can't allow same user anymore. Restart the server and close all connection after each usage.

Comment: I am logging them off.  I get this error even when users use the app for the first time.